# Oracle to MS-Access SQL:

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I'm trying to replicate a SQL code from Oracle to my Access to automate the creation of some reports. So far I have been successful but I am having trouble with one:

This is Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o587265.PROJECT_NUMBER AS E587273,
    o587265.PROJECT_NAME AS E587274,
    o587265.PROJECT_STATUS_CODE AS E587275,
    o587265.PROJECT_MANAGER AS E587276
FROM (
    SELECT p.segment1 project_number,
        p.NAME project_name,
        p.project_status_code,
        (
            SELECT a.FULL_NAME
            FROM apps.per_all_people_f a,
                apps.pa_project_players_v pm
            WHERE a.person_id = pm.person_id
                AND pm.project_ID = p.project_ID
                AND pm.ROLE = 'Project Manager'
                AND a.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
                AND a.person_type_id = 1
                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN a.effective_start_date
                    AND a.effective_end_date
                AND SYSDATE BETWEEN pm.start_date_active(+)
                    AND NVL(pm.end_date_active, SYSDATE)
            ) project_manager
    FROM apps.pa_projects_all p
    WHERE p.project_status_code != 'CLOSED'
        AND p.template_flag = 'N'
        AND p.org_ID = 5003
    ) o587265
    ORDER BY o587265.PROJECT_NUMBER ASC,
    o587265.PROJECT_NAME ASC,
    o587265.PROJECT_MANAGER ASC;
```

And this is my current MS-Access version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o587265.PROJECT_NUMBER AS E587273,
    o587265.PROJECT_NAME AS E587274,
    o587265.PROJECT_STATUS_CODE AS E587275,
    o587265.PROJECT_MANAGER AS E587276
FROM (
    SELECT p.segment1 AS project_number,
        p.NAME AS project_name,
        p.project_status_code,
        (
            SELECT a.FULL_NAME
            FROM ((apps_per_all_people_f AS a INNER JOIN apps_pa_project_players_v AS pm ON a.person_id = pm.person_id
                ) INNER JOIN apps_pa_projects_all AS p ON pm.project_ID = p.project_ID
            )
            WHERE pm.ROLE = 'Project Manager'
                AND a.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
                AND a.person_type_id = 1
                AND DATE () BETWEEN a.effective_start_date
                AND a.effective_end_date
                AND DATE () BETWEEN pm.start_date_active
                AND IIf(IsNull(pm.end_date_active), DATE (), pm.end_date_active)
            ) AS PROJECT_MANAGER
    FROM apps_pa_projects_all AS p
    WHERE p.project_status_code <> 'CLOSED'
        AND p.template_flag = 'N'
        AND p.org_ID = 5003
    ) AS o587265
ORDER BY o587265.PROJECT_NUMBER ASC,
    o587265.PROJECT_NAME ASC,
    o587265.PROJECT_MANAGER ASC;
```

The first one runs directly on Oracle 11g (SQL Developer) and works. The MS-Access one seems to be returning more than one row in the subquery. I exhausted my knowledge but I can't seem to replicate it.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, what is this (+) operator in the Oracle SQL code?

I've known this operator as a OUTER (LEFT/RIGHT) JOIN but I never saw it being used like that and that is definitely not a JOIN.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `(+)` really is a left outer join operator, even in this case.  But it doesn't look like it worked, because it wasn't applied consistently.  I think you can remove it from the Oracle query, and it won't change anything.

Comment: You should try rewriting the Oracle query to use explicit joins.  At the very least, you would be left having an understanding of what the query is actually doing.

Comment: sstan: (+) I though so too but in this case it isn't. This query was extract from Oracle Discovery interface and it is used as it is to generate a report so it does work. I did remove it and it didn't change anything.

Comment: tim: already did and already worked in Oracle. I think I'm using something wrong in MS-ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly in the translation of Oracle's implicit join for MS Access explicit join, you added an additional `INNER JOIN` referencing the *apps_pa_projects_all* table in the derived table's subquery for *PROJECT_MANAGER* column, replacing the alias *p*. However, this subquery correlated to the outer `FROM` clause's derived table, *apps_pa_projects_all* with original alias *p*:

Consider removing the second `INNER JOIN` and returning the correlated `WHERE` clause condition:

**ORIGINAL**

```
...
    (
        SELECT a.FULL_NAME
        FROM ((apps_per_all_people_f AS a 
        INNER JOIN apps_pa_project_players_v AS pm 
                ON a.person_id = pm.person_id) 
        INNER JOIN apps_pa_projects_all AS p 
                ON pm.project_ID = p.project_ID)
        WHERE pm.ROLE = 'Project Manager'
         AND a.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
         ...
```

**CHANGE**

```
...
    (
        SELECT a.FULL_NAME
        FROM apps_per_all_people_f AS a 
        INNER JOIN apps_pa_project_players_v AS pm 
                ON a.person_id = pm.person_id
        WHERE pm.project_ID = p.project_ID
         AND pm.ROLE = 'Project Manager'
         AND a.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
         ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still didn't work. ODBC returned "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows". However, the Oracle SQL (using SQL Developer) returns exact 1648 records. My understanding is that MS-ACCESS is returning way more records with the same query for some reason. Maybe Access is not understanding something in the where clause?

Comment: Replace the subquery's `SELECT` with `SELECT TOP 1`. Also, try running subquery separately conditioned on a particular `project_ID` and see if multiple entries return.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you a lot Parfait. Using that strategy helped me track the problem. It seems Oracle had a Project_Number field that was described as decimal (15), but contained String names in there (it was a View but even so, I can't understand how Oracle could not enforce such constraint). After I eliminated it, your suggestion worked.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Please accept answer to confirm resolution. By the way, do note MS Access has pass-through queries that allows you to retain exact SQL syntax from backend RDMS (and not conform to Access' dialect). However, such queries cannot join to local Access tables unless you convert them with make-table/append action queries.